# Object Notations and user defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am fairly new at all the object notations and object literals. I am trying to generate a small plugin for my users on a help site. And well I am having some problems.

```
$(function() {
  var newGroup='<div class="editor-group"></div>';
  easyBB = {
    add: {
      button: function(cmd,begin,end,tooltip) {

      },
  DropDown: function(cmd,name,content) {
     var dropdown = '<div class="editor-dropdown sceditor-'+cmd+' />';
     $('body').append(dropdown);
     dropdown.append(content);
    $('sceditor-button-'+cmd).on('click',function() {
        if(this.style.display=="block"){
           $(this).hide();
          }else {
       x= $(this).cmd.offsetTop;
         console.log(x);
       y= this.cmd.offsetLeft;
         console.log(y);
    dropdown.style.position="absolute";
    dropdown.style.left=y;
    dropdown.style.top=x;
       this.show(); 
      }
    });
}

},

theme:  {
  dark: function() {},
  light: function() {},
  background: function() {},
  hoverButton: function() {},
  button: function() {},
  border: function() {}
},

destroy: {
  button: function(name) {
    $('.editor-button-'+name).remove();
  },

  group: function() {
    var $current = $();
    var $group =  $('.sceditor-group');
  for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
     $current = $current.add($group).eq(arguments[i]);
  }
  $current.remove();
  }
},

removeWYSIWYG: function() {
easyBB.destroy.button('source');
   }
  };
 });
```

Basically what I want my user to be able to do is the following code implementation

```
easyBB.add.button('buttonName','[b]',false,'Title of Button');
```

So now we have out button name, opening bbcode to insert, false that it doesn't need to be closed, and tooltip. I need to figure out how to set the closed to be true unless other wise stated. Does it need to be set, or could I just do:

```
   if(end === false) {
       alert('ready');
    } else {
      alert('done');
    }
```

And doing so it will not allow me to do this... Maybe as it is because of the opening used as the closing? Example code below

```
   if(closed === false){
      $('#text_editor_textarea').val('['+tag+']');
    } else{
      $('#text_editor_textarea').val('['+tag+'][/'+tag+']');
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*it will not allow me to do this*"? Does this throw an error? Does it do something unexpected?

Comment: Unexpected as it won't insert it at all. It will if I set the parameter to false only.

Comment: If someone just calls `easyBB.add.button('buttonName', '[b]')`, then `end` will be `undefined` and your condition is not fulfilled, so it will alert `done`. If you compare `closed` to anything, it will throw an exception since that variable is not declared anywhere.